# error on line 2 at column 59: SystemLiteral " or ' expected

Tags: ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I am getting such error in my iOS application when I am going to open some web pages using buil-in web view engine (based on Safari but Safari works fine):

> This page contains the following errors: error on line 2 at column 59:
>   SystemLiteral " or ' expected. Below is a rendering of the page up to
>   the first error.

(nothing is rendered).
The funny thing is that these websites can be opened on iPhone's version of my app but not on iPad.
Looking into the Internet I found hundreds of thousands websites which cannot be handled by google robots - when I search in google:

> "59: SystemLiteral " or ' expected"

it lists search results but all found websites' descriptions shows my error. However when I open any of them they are rendering fine on desktop browser and iOS Safari.
Anybody knows what may be the reason of that? Non of websites opened from this google search can be rendered in my app on iPad - all shows the same error.

I also tried debug it using Mac's Safari Developer mode but it does not give any hint.

Update: I prepared a minimal project, added UIWebView controller and it shows the same error.
ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://catalog.llc.lib.ms.us/polaris/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

I also tried few web pages with this code (all from google search I mentioned above), they show also different erros, like "error on line 1077 at column 9: Opening and editing tag mismatch: META line 0 and head." - this comes from http://www.lucindalayton.com/home/?ID=15449 but still they cannot be rendered.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: any of web pages gives the same error but the first line with code is the number from error and usually it is... 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
or similar

Comment: @Rob I am not sure if it is programming question, it is rather question if this is app problem or bad code on website side. I am wondering why google is not handling it as well in search engine. I use the same code for iPhone and iPad, my app is too big to show the code.

Comment: @Rob I am asking if anyone met such problem or may give at least some hints. From what I can see it is quite common issue looking at number of exactly the same found errors. I will try to prepare some simple app but I guess it is not the clue.

Comment: Good edit, @Hiero. I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob, thanks from hint but in my case it was something else. I found breakthrough analysing communication between browser and server using some test web page.
 I will explain it in details:
The problem is related to user agent and mime type.
My application was containing in user agent string, among other things,

```
"Mobile/[somenumber] Safari Version/[someversionnumber]"
```

Some servers are very strict what comes in user agent and for mobile Safari-based browsers are expecting some Safari webkit version so the proper notation should be

```
"Mobile/[somenumber] Safari/[someverionnumber] Version/[someversionnumber]"
```

Notation affects behavior of the server - it sends different mime type (Content-Type). For websites I mentioned in the qestion when user agent is improper "Content-Type" is set by server to "application/xhtml+xml", but when is proper it is "text/html" which is rendered without any problems. Html code sent in both cases is exactly the same.

Anyway, for me it is still hard to say if it is server site fault, which lets sending "application/xhtml+xml" content type to mobile device, or webkit which should handle such code anyway or very strict user agent notation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the response from that web site, it has a blank line at the start of the response, which seemed a little curious. In my first attempt, I trimmed that whitespace:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString     *fullURL = @"http://catalog.llc.lib.ms.us/polaris/";
    NSURL        *url     = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!data) {
            NSLog(@"%s: sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, connectionError);
            return;
        }
        NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:url];
    }];
}
```

But I later noticed that you don't have to trim the whitespace, but rather merely using `loadHTMLString` seemed to be enough.

I'm unclear as to why Safari handles this properly, as does the iPhone web view, but not the iPad web view. But this seems to get around it.